# Python check list inside other list

Tags: python, list, recursion, performance

I need to run through 2 lists (those lists are 'lists of lists') each item on those lists contain [path,md5] and make an if statement that works like this:
(logically)

```
save_list = []
for small_list2 in big_list2:
    for small_list1 in big_list1:
        if small_list2[0] == small_list1[0] and small_list2[1] != small_list2[1]:
           save_list.append(small_list2)
```

Is this the way? And, there is a better (maybe recursive way) to do that??

Thanks !!

EDIT:
sample input:(the md5 are not real nor reasonable)
[PATH,MD5]

big_list2 = [['/home/user/Desktop/folder/1.txt','93n8nv35732vb9527'],['/home/user/Desktop/folder/2.txt','43284fh234h'],['/home/user/Desktop/folder/3.txt','4534v4535v353']]

big_list1 = [['/home/user/Desktop/folder/1.txt','93n8nv35732vb9528'],['/home/user/Desktop/folder/2.txt','43284fh234h'],['/home/user/Desktop/folder/3.txt','4534v4535v353']]

the output should be :
'/home/user/Desktop/folder/1.txt','93n8nv35732vb9527'
because its the same path but different md5

Comment: Can you provide a sample input?

Comment: `save_list = [[path2, md5_2] for path2, md5_2 in big_list2 for path1, md5_1 in big_list1 if path2 == path1 and md5_2 != md5_1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming neither `small_list1` nor `small_list2` contains repeated paths (paths that appear in both lists are fine), it sounds like you should be using dicts. Instead of lists of `[path, md5]` lists, make dicts mapping paths to checksums. Then, you can efficiently look up the checksums for each path:

```
path_dict1 = something()
path_dict2 = something_else()
save_list = [(path, md5) for path, md5 in path_dict2.viewitems()
             if md5 != path_dict1.get(path)]
```

This will run much faster than the list-based solution, which takes time proportional to the product of the lengths of the input lists. This solution takes time proportional to the number of paths.

Comment: I thought about it, but I have duplicated path .. So Not very good.

Comment: @FernandoRetimo: Duplicates within a list, or just duplicates between the lists? Because duplicates between the lists are expected, and this solution handles them fine, but duplicates within a list sound like a problem.

Comment: (It's simple enough to adapt the solution to handle duplicates within a list, but if you have duplicates within a list, you may have bigger problems.)

Comment: Thank You, Managed do handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do some crazy list comprehension thing in one line. But I don't think it would be very readable.

```
save_list = [small_list2 for small_list2 in big_list2 for small_list1 in big_list1 if small_list2[0] == small_list1[0] and small_list2[1] != small_list2[1]]
```

Yeah...please don't write it like that. :P

Anyways your code/idea seems to be right but there's no way to really verify without sample input.